# How to add verification service to a website?

Tags: service, identity, verification

I am currently looking for a verification service for personal and business. For example I will have a user either pick a personal or business account for the website. If the user decides on having a personal account than they would have to be check from the verification service to prove their identity. I am not sure if there is even a service that verifies a business.

Would it be possible to place a third parthy identity verfication service in the website?

I want to do this so that users can trust one another to do business with them especially knowing that they have to go through a verification process in order to go on the website. Verification can't always be 100% scam proof but it will be at least alot more comfortable to use.

How could a programmer/designer intergate this into a website? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Sean, a similar system has already been set up called OpenID - it works on the basis of a third party provider looking after the user registrations and is in fact in use on this website. Anyone can sign up here using an OpenID - stackoverflow doesn't need to trust them because OpenID providers can be "trusted", that's the logic.

What you're talking about sounds like you want extra checks done by the OpenID provider. I have no idea if such a system exists - as it is, anyone can register an OpenID and there is no verification procedure that that person is who they say they are.